# Delete raw pointer after creating a shared_ptr from it

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr, raw-pointer

If I do the following,

```
int* p = new int(10);
std::shared_ptr<int>(p);
delete p;
```

What happens here? Is the `shared_ptr` invalid after deletion of the raw pointer? Is there any way to ensure memory access safety in such a scenario?

Comment: can i ask why you need to do this? I mean why not use `shared_ptr` at the first place

Comment: I have an function which takes in a shared_ptr as a parameter. I am just trying to find cases where my function will misbehave if the client of the API does stupid things like above, and to see if there is anything I can do in my function to stop this from happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, if your client decides to shoot himself in the foot, there's not a whole lot you can do about it.

Comment: Is there anything you can do? I tend to doubt it. Where there's a will, there's way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in your question contains 2 conflicting definitions of `p`. I'm assuming you meant to post something like

```
int* p = new int(10);
std::shared_ptr<int> p1(p);
delete p;
```

When the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope and its reference count falls to zero it will attempt to `delete p;`, leading to double deletion and undefined behavior.

You've passed ownership of the dynamically allocated `int` to the `shared_ptr`, so let it do its job, and don't go about deleting the `int` yourself.

---

If you want clients of your API from doing something similar to the code above, one possibility is to change the API function's parameter type from a `shared_ptr` to a parameter pack of constructor arguments. For instance

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void api_func(Args&&... args)
{
    auto p = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // Use the shared_ptr p as before
}
```

Then, instead of passing a `shared_ptr<int>`, client code would call the above function as `api_func<int>(10);`.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<int>(p);` creates a temporary value. It is not a declaration of `p`. At the point of calling `delete p;` the memory has already been freed by the `shared_ptr` destructor.

Comment: @tsuki No, the parentheses are redundant there, so it's a declaration of a `shared_ptr<int>` named `p` (in this case it's a redeclaration of `p`, hence an error).

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. Sorry, I was trying to be smart without running the code.

Comment: @tsuki Come to think of it, maybe the OP meant to use braces instead of parentheses. `std::shared_ptr<int>{p}`; would do exactly what you said in your first comment. The end result is the same though, undefined behavior.

Comment: One could write `return std::shared_ptr<int>(p)` though if it was a function, right? In this case it would be a constructor call would it not? So how does this differ from the OP's code. To me it looks the same - creating a temporary by calling it's constructor.

Comment: @rozina that was my original assumption, but for some weird reason you can parenthesize the variable name and still get a variable declaration. That's some weird C++ quirk right there...